# getting a value to become true in a submit handler

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm working on project where I have an an accordion with checkboxes. When the checkboxes have a value of true they go to my `trueItems` array. I have an array `filter` that I need to register the change of value to true when the button with `handleSubmit` is clicked. The issue that I'm having is with the final part. I'm struggling to figure out how to get the variables in `filter` to change to true. I've tried: `x => {setFilter({...filter, x,}), true` but that didn't do anything, and I've tried `x => {setFilter({...filter, x: true,}),` 
but that didn't work either. I would really appreciate any help or advice on how to do this. Thank you!

```
function handleSubmit () {
for (var items of trueItems){
      for (var x in filter){
        if(x === items.name) {
          x => {
            setFilter({
              ...filter,
              x,
            })
  }}}}}
```

where filter is:

```
 const [filter, setFilter] = useState({
        pescatarian: false,
        vegan: false,
        vegetarian: false,
        ...
      });
```

and trueItems is:

```
[{"name": " pescatarian", "value": true}...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a state variable with [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html), it returns a pair — an array with two items.

The first item is the current value, and the second is a function that lets you update it.

Then use [spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to update the original state.

```
setFilter((currentFilter) => ({
  ...currentFilter,
  ...trueItems.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    return acc[curr['name']] = curr['value'], acc;
  }, {})
}));
```

Below is a complete code snippet, you can refer to it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script crossorigin src='https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js'></script>
    <script crossorigin src='https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='root'></div>
    <script type='text/babel'>
    const App = React.createElement(() => {
    
      const [filter, setFilter] = React.useState({
        'pescatarian': false,
        'vegan': false,
        'vegetarian': false
      });
      
      const trueItems = [
        { 'name': 'pescatarian', 'value': true },
        { 'name': 'vegetarian', 'value': true }
      ];

      const handleSubmit = React.useCallback(() => {
        setFilter((currentFilter) => ({
          ...currentFilter,
          ...trueItems.reduce((acc, curr) => {
            return acc[curr['name']] = curr['value'], acc;
          }, {})
        }));
      }, []);

      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <p>{JSON.stringify(filter)}</p>
          <button onClick={handleSubmit}>handleSubmit</button>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
      
    });

    ReactDOM.render(App, document.getElementById('root'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @Ian, I've added data to my original array, and now for some reason only the first and last objects in ```trueItems``` are being adding with their new value in the ```filter``` array. New format of ```trueItems```:  ```{subCategories: [ {name:'pescatarian', value: false }, {name:'vegan', value: false },  {name:'vegetarian', value: false }, ], subCategories: [{name:'A', value: false },{name:'B', value: false },  ], ... },```

Comment: so I have ```const datas = trueItems.map(x => x.subCategories) for (var items of datas) { setFilterData((currentFilter) => ({ ...currentFilter,  ...items.reduce((acc, curr) => {return acc[curr['label']] = curr['value'], acc; }, {})})); }```. Do you have any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Hi @Gigi101 Is the data format of trueItems like this?
const trueItems = [{
 subCategories: 
 [ 
  {name:'pescatarian', value: false}, 
  {name:'vegan', value: false},  
  {name:'vegetarian', value: false}
 ]
},{ 
 subCategories: 
 [
  {name:'A', value: false },
  {name:'B', value: false }
 ]
}];
Otherwise, according to the data format you provided, trueItems is `object`, and there is no `map` function.

Comment: And your `curr['label']` should be replaced with `curr['name']`, the name of the key is determined according to your data.

Comment: I suggest that you only need to set the state once, you don't need to loop to process, when your trueItems format is `[Array(3), Array(2)]`, you can use `flat()` method , which converts the format to `[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your needs correctly, this should work. It takes the previous filter state and iterates over trueValues to actualize the filter state. Your "name" in trueItems should match keys of filter object (I see extra space there)

```
setFilter((oldFilter) => {
  newFilter = {...oldFilter};
  trueItems.forEach(trueItem => {
    newFilter[trueItem.name] = trueItem.value;
  });
  return newFilter;
});
```